# clearTimeout only works on page reload JavaScript for SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I wrote this bit of JS to try to get the setTimout to clear on click using "clearTimeout". The problem I am facing, is that it only works after the first refresh. What is supposed to happen is the code is supposed to clear the timeout, so the years will stop progressing in the navigation. 
the function "addtoev" contains the function that should stop the code.

I have a link to my codepen here:

https://codepen.io/paula_athena/pen/MGrGyy

My JS is a mess as I literally do not know how to code but I was hoping I could at least get a timeout to clear

```
    var year2002;

    var year2003;

    var year2005;

    var year2007;

    var year2009;

    var year2011;

    var year2013;

    var year2015;

    var year2017;


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function autoPlay() {


    window.addEventListener("load",function() {   addtoev(); });


    function addtoev() {

   var bns = document.getElementsByClassName("cls-10");for (i = 0; i < 
   bns.length; i++) {


        bns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {


            clearTimeout(year2002);
            clearTimeout(year2003);
            clearTimeout(year2005);
            clearTimeout(year2007);
            clearTimeout(year2009);
            clearTimeout(year2011);
            clearTimeout(year2013);
            clearTimeout(year2015);
            clearTimeout(year2017);


          // alert("This element was clicked.");
         });   } }




    year2002 = window.setTimeout(function(){

$("#_2002").removeClass("hidden");  
$("#_2002 rect").addClass("color_change");   
$("#rect_02").addClass("blue_selected");   
$('#2002 text').addClass("text_wht");    
$('#asterisks_02').removeClass("hidden");


    }, 1000);


    year2003 = window.setTimeout(function()   {
        $("#_2003").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2003 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2002 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_02").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_03").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2003 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2002 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_03').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#asterisks_02').addClass("hidden");


      }, 3000);


    year2005 = window.setTimeout(function()

      {
        $("#_2005").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2005 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2003 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_03").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_05").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2005 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2003 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_05').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#asterisks_03').addClass("hidden");


    }, 5000);

    year2007 = window.setTimeout(function()

      {
        $("#_2007").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2007 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2005 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_05").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_07").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2007 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2005 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_05').addClass("hidden");

    }, 7000);



    year2009 = window.setTimeout(function(){

     $("#_2009").removeClass("hidden");   
     $("#_2009 rect").addClass("color_change");   
     $("#_2007 rect").removeClass("color_change");   
     $("#rect_07").removeClass("blue_selected");   
     $("#rect_09").addClass("blue_selected");   
     $('#2009 text').addClass("text_wht");   
     $('#2007 text').removeClass("text_wht");    
     $('#asterisks_09').removeClass("hidden");

      }, 9000);


    year2011 = window.setTimeout(function()   {
        $("#_2011").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2011 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2009 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_09").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_11").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2011 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2009 text').removeClass("text_wht");
         $('#asterisks_11').removeClass("hidden");
         $('#asterisks_09').addClass("hidden");

      }, 11000);


    year2013 = window.setTimeout(function()

      {
        $("#_2013").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2013 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2011 rect").removeClass("color_change");
            $("#rect_11").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_13").addClass("blue_selected");
            $('#2013 text').addClass("text_wht");
         $('#2011 text').removeClass("text_wht");
         $('#asterisks_11').addClass("hidden");

    }, 13000);

    year2015 = window.setTimeout(function()

      {
        $("#_2015").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2015 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2013 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_13").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_15").addClass("blue_selected");
            $('#2015 text').addClass("text_wht");
         $('#2013 text').removeClass("text_wht");
             $('#asterisks_15').removeClass("hidden");
          $('#asterisks_11').addClass("hidden");

    }, 15000);

    year2017 = window.setTimeout(function()

      {
        $("#_2017").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2017 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2005 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_15").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_17").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2017 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2015 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_17').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#asterisks_15').addClass("hidden");

    }, 17000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the click listener is not getting executed because you must click the button in a place that does not have letters. Try to change the listener to  button container.

Try to change this line:

```
bns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {...
```

For this one:

```
bns[i].parentElement.addEventListener("click", function(event) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, instead of declaring multiple variables for something that changes every year it would be better to use an array to store the values since you are clearing all of them every time anyway.

```
var timeouts = [];

// Add them to the array like this
timeouts.push(setTimeout(function(){ /*...*/ }, 1000));

// And clear them like this
for (let i = 0 ; i < timeouts.length ; i++) {
    clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
}
```

Secondly, I would wrap all those "buttons" in a group tag and put the click event handler on the parent instead of attaching multiple event handlers like you're doing:

```
<g id="button-tray">
  <g id="2017">
    <rect id="rect_17" class="cls-10" x="708.07" y="550.46" width="65.91" height="47.54"></rect>
    <text class="cls-19" transform="translate(727.98 593.05)">MR</text>
    <text class="cls-20" transform="translate(716.05 571.44)">2017</text>
  </g>
  <!-- ... --> 
  <g id="2002">
    <rect id="rect_02" class="cls-10" x="41.09" y="550.46" width="65.91" height="47.54"></rect>
    <text class="cls-19" transform="translate(60.72 593.05)">MR</text>
    <text class="cls-20" transform="translate(50.1 571.44)">2002</text>
  </g>
</g>
```

Then you can attach the handler like this:

```
$("#button-tray").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target); // This is how you reference the clicked element

    for (let i = 0 ; i < timeouts.length ; i++) {
        clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
    }
});
```

Thirdly and most importantly, the click event is not firing when the *text* on the button is clicked.  You can test this with the following code:

```
bns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("TEST");
}
```

To solve your problem, the following code will work if you add the parent element:

```
var timeouts = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function autoPlay() {

    window.addEventListener("load",function() {
        addtoev();
    });

    function addtoev() {
      $(#'button-tray').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            for (let i = 0 ; i < timeouts.length ; i++) {
                clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
            }
         });
      }
    }

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
      $("#_2002").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#_2002 rect").addClass("color_change");
      $("#rect_02").addClass("blue_selected");
      $('#2002 text').addClass("text_wht");
      $('#asterisks_02').removeClass("hidden");
    }, 1000));

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#_2003").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2003 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2002 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_02").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_03").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2003 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2002 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_03').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#asterisks_02').addClass("hidden");
    }, 3000));

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#_2005").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2005 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2003 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_03").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_05").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2005 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2003 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_05').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#asterisks_03').addClass("hidden");
    }, 5000));

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#_2007").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2007 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2005 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_05").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_07").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2007 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2005 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_05').addClass("hidden");
    }, 7000));

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
      $("#_2009").removeClass("hidden");
      $("#_2009 rect").addClass("color_change");
      $("#_2007 rect").removeClass("color_change");
      $("#rect_07").removeClass("blue_selected");
      $("#rect_09").addClass("blue_selected");
      $('#2009 text').addClass("text_wht");
      $('#2007 text').removeClass("text_wht");
      $('#asterisks_09').removeClass("hidden");
    }, 9000));

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#_2011").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2011 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2009 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_09").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_11").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2011 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2009 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_11').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#asterisks_09').addClass("hidden");
      }, 11000));

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#_2013").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2013 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2011 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_11").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_13").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2013 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2011 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_11').addClass("hidden");
    }, 13000));

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#_2015").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2015 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2013 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_13").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_15").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2015 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2013 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_15').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#asterisks_11').addClass("hidden");
    }, 15000));

    timeouts.push(window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#_2017").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#_2017 rect").addClass("color_change");
        $("#_2005 rect").removeClass("color_change");
        $("#rect_15").removeClass("blue_selected");
        $("#rect_17").addClass("blue_selected");
        $('#2017 text').addClass("text_wht");
        $('#2015 text').removeClass("text_wht");
        $('#asterisks_17').removeClass("hidden");
        $('#asterisks_15').addClass("hidden");
    }, 17000));

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try to add those items to an array.

I tried wrapping those svg buttons in a div, but it broke my inline SVG. Does wrapping sections of an inline svg in a div usually work?

Comment: @siren_dev use a <g> not a div.  My mistake - updated